# Image slider demo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Since I'm new to web development, I've decided to create [this carousel](http://jsfiddle.net/aletaie/9n8avyk7/), to practice a bit of JavaScript, more specifically jQuery. I'm really happy with the result, but I'm sure that to an expert my code would look like a disaster, so I would love if someone could help me make the JavaScript of this slider a bit "prettier".

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Configuration
    var width = 720;

    var animationSpeed = 1000;

    var pause = 4000;

    var currentSlide = 1;

    $('#dot1').addClass('activedot');


//Cache DOM

    var $slider = $('#slider');

    var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');

    var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');




//interval needs to be initially set to undefined since it must be a global variable
//to be used in the setInterval method
    var interval;




//slider starting motion
//right arrow function
    var moveForward = function() {


            $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {


               currentSlide++;


               if (currentSlide == 1) {

                    $('#dot1').addClass('activedot');
                    $('.dot').not('#dot1').removeClass('activedot');

                }else if (currentSlide == 2) {

                    $('#dot2').addClass('activedot');
                    $('.dot').not('#dot2').removeClass('activedot');

                }else if (currentSlide == 3) {

                    $('#dot3').addClass('activedot');
                    $('.dot').not('#dot3').removeClass('activedot');

                }else if (currentSlide == 4) {

                    $('#dot4').addClass('activedot');
                    $('.dot').not('#dot4').removeClass('activedot');

                }else if (currentSlide == 5) {

                    $('#dot5').addClass('activedot');
                    $('.dot').not('#dot5').removeClass('activedot');

                }else if (currentSlide == 6) {

                    $('#dot1').addClass('activedot');
                    $('.dot').not('#dot1').removeClass('activedot');

                };

                if(currentSlide === $slides.length) {

                    currentSlide = 1;
                   $slideContainer.css('margin-left',0);

                };

            });

        };



//left arrow function
    var moveBack = function(){


        if (currentSlide == 1) {

                $slideContainer.css('margin-left','-3600px');

                currentSlide=6;

        };

        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '+='+width}, animationSpeed, function(){


            currentSlide--;

            if (currentSlide == 1) {

                $('#dot1').addClass('activedot');
                $('.dot').not('#dot1').removeClass('activedot');

            }else if (currentSlide == 2) {

                $('#dot2').addClass('activedot');
                $('.dot').not('#dot2').removeClass('activedot');

            }else if (currentSlide == 3) {

                $('#dot3').addClass('activedot');
                $('.dot').not('#dot3').removeClass('activedot');

            }else if (currentSlide == 4) {

                $('#dot4').addClass('activedot');
                $('.dot').not('#dot4').removeClass('activedot');

            }else if (currentSlide == 5) {

                $('#dot5').addClass('activedot');
                $('.dot').not('#dot5').removeClass('activedot');

            }else if (currentSlide == 6) {

                $('#dot1').addClass('activedot');
                $('.dot').not('#dot1').removeClass('activedot');

            };

        });
    };  



//starting function
function startSlider(){

    interval = setInterval( moveForward, pause);

};



//pause function
function stopSlider() {

    clearInterval(interval);

}




//listen for mouseenter and pause
//resume on mouseleave
$slider.on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);




//start slider when page is loaded
startSlider();


//dot onclick functions 
$('#dot1').on('click', function(){

    $(this).addClass('activedot');

    $('.dot').not('#dot1').removeClass('activedot');

    $slideContainer.css('margin-left','0px');

    stopSlider();

    currentSlide = 1;
});


$('#dot2').on('click', function(){

    $(this).addClass('activedot');

    $('.dot').not('#dot2').removeClass('activedot');

    $slideContainer.css('margin-left','-720px');

    stopSlider();

    currentSlide = 2;
});


$('#dot3').on('click', function(){

    $(this).addClass('activedot');

    $('.dot').not('#dot3').removeClass('activedot');

    $slideContainer.css('margin-left','-1440px');

    stopSlider();

    currentSlide = 3;
});


$('#dot4').on('click', function(){

    $(this).addClass('activedot');

    $('.dot').not('#dot4').removeClass('activedot');

    $slideContainer.css('margin-left','-2160px');

    stopSlider();

    currentSlide = 4;
});


$('#dot5').on('click', function(){

    $(this).addClass('activedot');

    $('.dot').not('#dot5').removeClass('activedot');

    $slideContainer.css('margin-left','-2880px');

    stopSlider();

    currentSlide = 5;
});

//listen for mouse hovering over dots
$('.nav-dots').on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);



//arrow functions
$('.back').on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider).on('click', moveBack);

$('.forward').on('click', moveForward).on('mouseenter',stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);






//arrow keys function when key is pressed and focus is on html
$('html').keydown(function (key) {

    stopSlider();

    var pressedkey = (key.which);

    if (pressedkey == 37) {

        moveBack();

        startSlider();

    }else if (pressedkey == 39){

        moveForward();

        startSlider();  

     };

 });   



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting a more DRY approach, I suggest thinking about what is different and what is the same about the operations you are performing. Take this block, for example:

```
if (currentSlide == 1) {

    $('#dot1').addClass('activedot');
    $('.dot').not('#dot1').removeClass('activedot');

}else if (currentSlide == 2) {

    $('#dot2').addClass('activedot');
    $('.dot').not('#dot2').removeClass('activedot');

}else if (currentSlide == 3) {

    $('#dot3').addClass('activedot');
    $('.dot').not('#dot3').removeClass('activedot');

}else if (currentSlide == 4) {

    $('#dot4').addClass('activedot');
    $('.dot').not('#dot4').removeClass('activedot');

}else if (currentSlide == 5) {

    $('#dot5').addClass('activedot');
    $('.dot').not('#dot5').removeClass('activedot');

}else if (currentSlide == 6) {

    $('#dot1').addClass('activedot');
    $('.dot').not('#dot1').removeClass('activedot');

};
```

The only thing that is different is the index on `#dot` for the vast majority of iterations, so that could easily be boiled down to:

```
if(currentSlide < $slides.length) {
   var $curSlide = $('#dot'+currentSlide);
   $('.dot').removeClass('activedot');
   $curSlide.addClass('activedot');
}
```

Then you have the case of the last slide, which you are targeting with 2 conditions (`currentSlide == 6` and `currentSlides == $slides.length`). You can just handle both operations together.

```
$('.dot').removeClass('activedot');

if (currentSlide < $slides.length) {
   var $curSlide = $('#dot'+currentSlide);
   $curSlide.addClass('activedot');
} else {
   $('#dot1').addClass('activedot');
   currentSlide = 1;
   $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
}
```

Having said all of that, I think you should abandon the id targeting, use classes only and use `currentSlide` as the index for which element you want to target:

```
var $dots = $('.dot');
$dots.removeClass('activedot');

if (currentSlide === $slides.length) {
   currentSlide = 1;
   $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
}

$('.dot').eq(currentSlide-1).addClass('activedot');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9n8avyk7/11/

The same could be said about your series of event handlers you are adding:

```
$('#dot2').on('click', function(){

    $(this).addClass('activedot');

    $('.dot').not('#dot2').removeClass('activedot');

    $slideContainer.css('margin-left','-720px');

    stopSlider();

    currentSlide = 2;
});
```

This could be simplified to one event handler that either got the margin based on image width and the index of the image at the index of the clicked dot `dot(4) -> image(4)`:

```
$dots.on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $dots.removeClass('activedot');
    $this.addClass('activedot');
    stopSlider();
    currentSlide = $this.index(); 
});
```

I didn't add the part setting the margin because I'm out of time at the moment, but you can get `$('.slide').eq(currentSlide).find('img')` and parse the image width (multipled by `currentSlide`) to get the pixel offset.

Comment: Great @AlexTaietti, glad to help :)

Comment: I think I've fixed it, if you want you can check the final code here http://jsfiddle.net/aletaie/9n8avyk7/ :)...do you see anything else that could be cut from the code?